# Apache mod_rewrite : RewriteRule to pass requests tomcat application

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am having difficulty defining a correct RewriteRule to forward requests to an application running in tomcat.  I have apache with mod_rewrite enabled as well as tomcat setup with an application mounted with mod_jk.  Without a virtual host, I can browse to the following url without issue. *(context being the application running in tomcat)*

```
http://www.domain.com/context
```

How do I configure the RewriteRule to pass requests from domain.com to the application running in tomcat.

```
http://www.domain.com --> http://www.domain.com/context
```

Here is what my current virtual host file looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule \/$ /context [L]
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/context/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny                                         
                allow from all                                           
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This will pass the request from `domain.com` to a directory named `context` in `/var/www/html`.  How do I override the default apache setup to pass the request to the application running in tomcat?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks. My RewriteRule is working in a sense, its passing the request to a directory named after my tomcat application in apache web directory (/var/www/html/context).  I need to override this so that the request get passed to tomcat, not to the context directory in apache.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, where localhost:8080 is where your tomcat server is running.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/context/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I gave that a try but got 'You don't have permission to access / on this server.'

Comment: Try adding "Allow from all" to the first Directory section
    <Directory />
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

Comment: I tried a couple variations with the information you gave, was unable to get to work.  I did however find a workable solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I edited my virtual host file.  I added the JkMount inside the virtual host file instead of 000-default.conf and was able to get apache to pass the request to the tomcat application instead of the folder in apaches web directory.  I also now have 2 virtual host files, one for the main domain and the other for the domain without www. prefix.  Here is what they look like :

**www_domain.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.domain.com

        JkMount /context* ajp13_worker

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule \/$ /context [L]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**domain.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule \/$ http://www.domain.com [L] 
</VirtualHost>
```